# Глубокое долгожительство

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, словосочетания

Из телепрограммы:
*Считается, что употребление этой воды позволяет им **дожить до глубокого долгожительства.***

[В передаче шла речь об особенной воде: талой ледниковой, горных рек и озер, подземных источников.]

Фраза "дожить до глубокого долгожительства" мне показалась "некомфортной".
А как вы считаете — правильно ли так говорить?

Answer (score 2):

Да уж!...

Во-первых, тавтология дожить - долгожительство.

Во-вторых, долгожительство - это, судя по определению медицинской энциклопедии, социально биологическое явление, характеризующееся доживаемостью человека до высоких возрастных рубежей (свыше 90 лет) …

Дожить можно до глубокой старости, до высоких возрастных рубежей, на худой конец до рубежа долгожительства,  но **не до долгожительства.** Так что я тоже считаю эту фразу "некомфортной".

Answer (score 1):

Правильно было сказать "*становиться* долгожителями", "дожи**ва**ть до *глубокой* старости (до преклонного возраста)".

*Долгожительство* - настолько абстрактное понятие, что едва ли можно "*достигать долгожительства*" (вместо "*долголетия*").